# How do i increase size by the value provided as parameter

Tags: java

So this code currently just displays a number that is inputed by the user i.e if 65.2 is inputed as a parameter in the main it displays 65.2. But i need to make a method called update that allows the size variable to be updated by the variable put in as a parameter

```
public class Population {

    // creates a private double variable called size
    private double size;
    // creates a constructor that uses x as the parameter to get the value of size
    Population(double x) {
        this.size = x;
    }
    // makes the size variable public by creating a public method so that it can be sent to the main also returns the value of size
    public double getSize() {
        return size;

    }
    public void update() {

    }
```

**and this is my main**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Population popSize = new Population(65.2);
        System.out.print(popSize.getSize());
    }

}
```

Comment: If you wrote the code above, then writing your `update` function will be trivial.  You'll need a parameter, like your constructor.

Comment: i've never done an update function and i only started learning a few months ago

Comment: What does your update function have to do?  Describe it in words.  If you describe it in words, you can write the code.

Answer (score 0):

To update a private member of a class you must do it inside the class itself. So, if you want to use a method to update the private member then you must pass it as parameter.

A method will be in following format `<access modifier of the method> <return type> <method name>(<parameter type> parameterName,....)`

So if you want to use `update` method with a parameter to update `size` in the class `Population` then your update method should be like

```java
public void update(double x){
    this.size = x;
}
```

In the above example the access modifier is `public` so this method is accessible everywhere and the return type of the method is `void` so this method doesn't return anything, you have a single parameter with type `double` and name `x`. Inside the method you can do anything you want, in the above example you just assign the passed value to the `size`, but if you want to do some calculations you can do that.

So, to use the update method you can do as follows.

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Population popSize = new Population(65.2);
    popSize.update(82.3);
    System.out.print(popSize.getSize());
}
```

The above code will print `82.3` since you have updated the instance variable.